# What is the default WindowBytesStoreSupplier for stream-stream join in Kafka Streams?

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

The new API has a signature of:

`join(KStream<K,VO> otherStream, ValueJoiner<? super V,? super VO,? extends VR> joiner, JoinWindows windows, StreamJoined<K,V,VO> streamJoined)`

If I only set store name using `StreamJoined<K,V,VO> streamJoined` parameter, what would be the default configuration of `WindowBytesStoreSupplier` in terms of `retentionPeriod`, `windowSize` and `retainDuplicates`? It's not clear from documentation. Is this an in memory state store? Or default one configured by Kafka Streams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only set the store name with `StreamJoined` then:

1. The `windowSize` comes from what you provide the [`JoinWindows`](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/JoinWindows.html#size--) configuration object.  Even if you use a custom `WindowBytesStoreSupplier`, Kafka Streams validates that the supplier window settings match the settings of the provided `JoinWindows` object.  So a `JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(30))` would have a `windowSize` equal to `30000` ms.
2. The `retentionPeriod` is the window size + the grace period.  The default grace period is 24 hours.
3. The `retainDuplicates` configuration is `true`.  But even when providing a custom `StoreSupplier`, the `retainDuplicates` field must be set to `true`.
4. The store type is a persistent (RocksDB) store, configured by Kafka Streams, as described above.

Also, note that with `StreamJoined`, you can now provide your own `StoreSupplier` for both sides of the join, so it's possible to have in-memory stores.

HTH,

Bill